# Cardview custom design in Android

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm working CardView.Everything workng perfect but i have one problem(question)
[image: Is it a possible to get like this background in cardView]

I only have png image.How i can solve my problem? is it a possible to use .9.png in my cardivew?

Comment: can you share your code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure You can use .9.png format Or use this link for making 5 diffrent screen size image for your app. LInk:

[Link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)